# How to echo value from php to html

Tags: php, html

how do i echo a value from php to html in a division (div2--a div i created) of a paragraph(p).

for example: i have a value called $greetings and i assign a value of "Welcome" to it

**$greetings = "Welcome";**

I tried:

```
`<p>
    <?php
       $index = "WELCOME"; 
       echo "<div2>$index</div2>";
     ?>
 </p>`
```

but it doesn't display the value of **$greetings--welcome**
instead it displays (  **$index"; ?>**  )

HERES MY ENTIRE CODE:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tech Planet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<img src="logo.gif" alt="logo" width="150" height="50">
<div class ='seachAndProducts'><form  action="header.php" method="GET">
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search Tech Planet...">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
</form></div>
<div class = 'navAndFooter'><ul>
<li><a href="index.html"><b>Home</b></a></li>
<li><a href="test.php"><b>Products</b></a></li>
<li><a href=""><b>About</b></a></li>
<li><a href=""><b>Contact us</b></a></li>
</ul></div>
<a href="default.asp"><img src="cart.jpg" alt="cart" width="40" height="40"></a>
</head>

<body>
<h3><img src="WelcometoTechPlanet.gif" width="250" height="40"></h3>
<h5><div class ='ourAndFeatProductsHeader'>Our Products</div>
<div class='seachAndProducts'>
<a href=""><div class='ourProductsList'>Audio Systems</div></a>
<a href=""><div class='ourProductsList'>Cameras</div></a>
<a href=""><div class='ourProductsList'>Laptops</div></a>
<a href=""><div class='ourProductsList'>Memory Cards</div></a>
<a href=""><div class='ourProductsList'>Monitors</div></a>
<a href=""><div class='ourProductsList'>Phones</div></a>
<a href=""><div class='ourProductsList'>Televisions</div></a>
<a href=""><div class='ourProductsList'>USBs</div></a>
<a href=""><div class='ourProductsList'>All Products</div></a>
</div><div class ='ourAndFeatProductsHeader'>Featured Products</div>
<div2><img src="8wb50.gif" alt="" width="250" height="200"></div2></h5>
<p><?php
$index = "WELCOME"; 
echo "<h1>$index</h1>";
?></p>
<!-- used &copy because © displays Â© -->
<div class = 'navAndFooter'>&copy Tech Planet. All Rights Reserved.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The PHP script isn't being executed by PHP. A browser would render your script (plain text) as HTML in the way you described.

Comment: Also, you aren't going to get the value of $greetings by echoing $index.

Comment: probably solvable by changing filename to *.php

Comment: Or you can add html to be handle by php server.

Comment: I see a link to an asp page in there. Are you sure you want php and not asp?

Comment: Are you just running this on your own computer?  If so, do you have PHP installed on it?

Comment: please do not set variables in between html, also your code seems useless, why not just print welcome

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to note...

Don't put an h1 tag in the p tag; and you are echoing $index, not $greetings.

Try this

```
<?php

// Pick the one you want.

$greetings = "Welcome";
$index = "WELCOME"; 

// Pick the one you want

echo "<h1>$index</h1>";
echo "<h1>$greetings</h1>";
?>
```

Then, make sure you save it as a .php file, and that you are on a web server with php enabled.